# Prevent PowerPoint in rewriting my hyperlinks

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2003

Using PowerPoint 2003 and saving a document on the fileserver. Within the document there is a hyperlink to a document located on another location on the same file server.

My original hyperlink:

```
\\fileserver\folder1\document.doc
```

After I save the PowerPoint document, it's rewritten to:

```
../../folder1/document.doc
```

I know relative paths is usually better than absolute, but I need this to be an absolute path. The document will be published to different recipients by email, and with relative paths the hyperlink is worthless.

Help me please... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess I found the answer myself.

In Options and Web Settings I unchecked a Update links on save option and it works like a charm....